# Problem in using gmapping with tf (tf2_msg/tfMessage) topic

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I am trying to use the gmapping node which subscribes to tf (tf/tfMessage) and scan (sensor_msgs/LaserScan) topics but the published topics (map and map_metadata) are unknown. I guess the problem is that I am publishing  **tf (tf2_msgs/tfMessage)** instead of **tf (tf/tfMessage)** but I don't know how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance

I launch gmapping using the following code

```
  <node pkg="gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" args="scan:=scan" respawn="false" output="screen">
  </node>
```

Edit: Here is my tf Tree

[image: image description]

And my rviz view:

[image: image description]

My topics being published:

[image: image description]

And my node graphs

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218512/problem-in-using-gmapping-with-tf-(tf2_msg/tfmessage)-topic/) by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 397 on 2015-10-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-10-01**:
Hi, your question is that when you use `rostopic  echo /map` and there is none map data, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use gmapping, you also need odometry message ( `nav_msgs/Odometry`) if you want to create `map`.
You can test it with `stage_ros`.
[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) with karma: 224 on 2015-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2015-10-02**:
Thank you for your answer. I am trying to do the mapping with my robot, I created a similar tf Tree unless the laser frame is "base_laser" instead of "base_laser_link". I still have problem. In rviz I get an error in front of Map/Transform : No transform from [ ] to [map]

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-10-02**:
Well, please check your TF tree. Or put more details about your problem.

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2015-10-02**:
Thank you for your help, I added more information to the question :) Looking forward to your answer

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-10-04**:
change the `fixed frame` to `map`, have a try.
I wonder if you have the data of `map`? try `rostopic echo /map`

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2015-10-04**:
Thank you for your answer, it is solved. It was a problem with rviz ...

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-10-04**:
Woo, good luck!